# How do I render multiple pipelines in MTKView draw?

Tags: swift, metal

I have one command buffer with two encoders, but I can only see the star field, not the player object. If I set them up separately (two buffers, two pipelines) they blink on and off.

I am assuming this is because I am doing something wrong with the buffer/encoder commands, but also perhaps my clear colors aren't set up right?

```
// PLAYER OBJECT ENCODER  ======================================================================


guard let renderPassDescriptor = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else { return }
let colorAttachment0 = renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0]!
let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!
let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptor)!
commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineState)
commandEncoder.setDepthStencilState(depthState)
colorAttachment0.texture = textures[0] // Texture object for color attachment 0
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(uniformsBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(modelMatricesBuffer, offset: 0, index: 2)
commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(textures[0], index: 0) // ship-diffuse
commandEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(textureSamplerState, index: 0)
commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(lightBuffer, offset: 0, index: 3)
commandEncoder.setFragmentBuffer(lightBuffer, offset: 0, index: 1)
if(totalVertexCount < 1){
print("WARNING: NO PRIMITIVES TO DRAW")
} else {
//            commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: totalVertexCount)
commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(type: .triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: totalVertexCount)
commandEncoder.endEncoding()
//            commandBuffer.present(view.currentDrawable!)
//            commandBuffer.commit()
}



// STARS ENCODER ======================================================================

guard let renderPassDescriptorStars = view.currentRenderPassDescriptor else { return }
let clearColor = MTLClearColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
renderPassDescriptorStars.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = clearColor
let commandEncoder2 = commandBuffer.makeRenderCommandEncoder(descriptor: renderPassDescriptorStars)!
commandEncoder2.setRenderPipelineState(pipelineStateStars)
commandEncoder2.setVertexBuffer(starsBuffer, offset: 0, index: 0)

stars.update()
let starsLengthBytes = MemoryLayout<Star>.stride * stars.stars.count
let starsBufferPointer = starsBuffer!.contents()
starsBufferPointer.copyMemory(from: stars.stars, byteCount: starsLengthBytes)
commandEncoder2.setVertexBuffer(starsBuffer, offset: 0, index: 4)

commandEncoder2.drawPrimitives(type: .point, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: stars.stars.count)
commandEncoder2.endEncoding()

commandBuffer.present(view.currentDrawable!)
commandBuffer.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

the default loadAction for a renderpass is to `clear`, meaning the target texture is fully overwritten at the start of each render pass. You can set it to `load` before consecutive render passes.

You tried to set the clearColor to fully transparent, which is logical, but think of it like this: If you want to mix the existing contents with something transparent, the machine will have to look at the existing content, i.e. load it first. This load costs resources, and is therefore not the default. `clear` will only write a value to each pixel, without loading, which is cheaper.

```
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .clear
    /* [first pass rendering] */
    /* then, before the second pass */
    renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .load
    /* [second pass rendering] */
```

or more specifically in your case, try:

```
renderPassDescriptorStars.colorAttachments[0].loadAction = .load
```